# GET parameters with inequalities

Tags: python, python-requests

I'm trying to use the `requests` library to do some HTTP GET/POST work. I have to generate a URL that looks like:

```
http://mysite/mypage.php?myval=>10
```

I can't seem to find anything other than:

```
r = requests.get("http://mysite/mypage.php", params={"myval":10})
```

which will result in a URL with `?myval=10`.

Is there a way to get the inequality in the URL? Fortunately I'm still exploring what packages to use so I'm not married to `requests` if this is something that just won't work.

Comment: why not just  `requests.get("http://mysite/mypage.php?myval=>"+str(param))`

Comment: @levi Because that was so completely obvious I didn't even think of it... ::facepalm::. Although if `requests` santizes/encodes the params in the dictionary, it means I need to make sure to do that step myself (not that it's hard, but it's something to keep track of)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Inequalities don't exist as a HTTP parameter concept.

The `>` may just need to be URL encoded.

HTTP Parameters are key=value pairs, so `myval=>10` might actually mean `myval` = `>10`.

To send though `>10`, try `%3E10` as `>` URL-encoded is `%3E`

Comment: Man, so embarrassing. I should be better at programming by now to not have to ask questions with such obvious answers. Thanks for ending my fruitless web-searching!

Comment: No problem @tpg2114, we all have those moments! If this has resolved your issue, please accept the answer. :D

Comment: No need to remind me about accepting :) I had to wait for the timer to expire before I could accept!

Comment: aaand there's my embarrassing moment, forgot about the timer!